# Concatenate text files BUT Inserting text between them

Tags: bash

I have found a brute force python programmatic way of concatenating multiple files while inserting some text characters in between the files.

Example:
`test_file1 + " \'id#\',\',name,\' " +...+ test_fileN`

BUT, is there a way to do this using only BASH commands (sed, grep, cat,...)?

Comment: You can use `{...}` command grouping and then i.e `{ cat file1; echo "foo bar baz"; cat file2 ; } > concat_all.txt`

Comment: yes, that would be good for a small number of files but not 100. TY

Answer (score 1):

I would type :

```
(for a in test_file*; do cat $a;echo " \'id#\',\',name,\' ";done) | sed '$d'
```

You just have to replace the `test_file*` by your actual name list (separated by spaces).

Answer (score 0):

Method using shell builtins `set`, `shift` and `printf`, with no loop:

```
echo " \'id#\',\',name,\' " > /tmp/foo
set -- test_file[0-9]*
f="$1"
shift
cat "$1" $(printf '/tmp/foo %s ' "$@")
rm /tmp/foo
```